# Minor as a mohel

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, brit-milah, minor-katan-child, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, is it permissible for a minor (under bar mitzvah) to serve as a mohel and do Brit Milah? What about B’dieved? The reason I ask is because some Poskim hold a woman can serve as Mohel despite not being obligated in circumcision, and also being circumcised after 8 days is an obligation for minors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H Milah 2:1:

> הכול, כשרים למול:  ואפילו הערל ועבד וקטן ואישה מולין, במקום שאין שם
> איש.  אבל גוי, לא ימול כלל; ואם מל, אינו צריך לחזור ולמולו שנייה.
>
> Circumcision may be performed by anyone. Even a person who is himself
> not circumcised, a slave, a woman, or a minor may perform the
> circumcision, if an adult male is not present. A gentile, however,
> should not be allowed to perform the circumcision at all.
> Nevertheless, if he does so, there is no need for a second
> circumcision.